# Survival Analysis where part of population never experiences event

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

We aim to examine the time it takes for a certain event to happen between two different groups of people in our sample. We are thinking of using survival analysis methods for this purpose.

The thing I am unsure about, for certain people in our sample, the event never occurs (and will never occur). The non-occurrence of the event is also a significant factor that distinguishes between the two groups we wish to compare.

I am not sure which method would be suitable for such an analysis. Which method would be best suited to handle the scenario I described above? Could you please direct me to some resources that can help me gain a better understanding of this setup?

Comment: Survival analysis naturally takes care of censored data, look at the likelihood function https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis in the section about fitting parameters to data. You could then look at the median survival time which is predicted and compare the two groups.

Comment: @Ggjj11 sometimes there is an important true "cure" aspect to survival over the time course of interest that goes beyond simple right censoring. In that situation, an estimate of the truly "cured" fraction is important. A recent example is cure of a fraction of cancer patients following "[checkpoint inhibitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkpoint_inhibitor)" therapy. Their cancer-specific survival is infinite (even though, in the long run, we are all dead from something).

Comment: I think that the question linked as a duplicate has an answer to your question; that answer has a link to a comprehensive recent review of the problem. [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/619834/28500) and answer from today go into some specific details. In general, what you are asking about is a "cure model" where you model both the time to event, given that one ultimately happens, and the probability of no event. If there are still outstanding issues, it probably would be best to ask a new question that gets specifically to those aspects.

Comment: The R [Survival Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/view=Survival) has links to some cure-modeling implementations.